# why class attribute assign by reference doesn't work?

Tags: php

```
class c{
    public $myV = &$_GET;
}
```

it gives me error :(

if i do a plain simple:

```
$myV = &$_GET;
```

it works

Comment: Why do you need this? If it gives you an error, it is probably not possible and you should consider another way. What do you want to do?

Comment: i need to set $myV to either $_GET $_POST or $_COOKIE

Comment: And why not pass it at runtime?

Comment: to doesn't have to type the default value everytime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot even do this:

```
public $x = $y;
```

From the manual:

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

To get around this, just set it in the `__construct` function.

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->myV = &$_GET;
}
```

Comment: @yes123, the "why" is because that property value is "hard coded" into the script at parse or "compile" time. If you reference a variable, PHP won't know what is in it until run time. This is a language design decision; I cannot answer the "why" did they design it in that way, as I wasn't part of that discussion.

Answer (score 2):

> ... but this initialization must be a
>   constant value--that is, it must be
>   able to be evaluated at compile time
>   and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

from [php.net : Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

You can define this dependency in a constructor though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class c {
    public $myV;

    function c() {
        $this->myV = &$_GET;
    }
}
```

You cannot assign variables to fields before a class is instantiated. This way, your variable will be set when an object is made from your class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar effect like:

```
class c{
   public $myV;
   function __construct() { $this->myV = &$_GET; }
}
```